# $EXP$ formula in excel using $e$

Tags: exponential-function

Can someone explain what this formula is doing?

$$=EXP(x)/(1+EXP(x))*100$$

If you are not familiar with $EXP$, $EXP$ calculates the $e^x$.

Thanks

Comment: Wikipedia explains it: [Sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)

Comment: It is used to represent something like, say sales.  There are 100 people in a city.  The first day you sell close to nothing.  The next day a little more.  Eventually, you will reach maximum sales in one day.  After that, sales decline.  Eventually, you will have no sales because almost all 100 people in your city bought your sales and you have no one to sell to.  This has happened before, e.g. game marketing.  Games sell fast and quick, then nearly no sales after that

Answer (score 2):

This is a sigmoid function, and it looks like this:

[image]